# how to take utf -8 characters from html form in spring controller characters like pi symbol , integration symbol

Tags: html, xml, jsp, spring-mvc

i have created virtual keyboard which contains special symbols like integration symbol , pi symbol but on submitting of form all virtual key board characters are showing like this âÏ? and  spring controller in console also look like this âÏ? ,
in jsp header and all i changed to UTF-8 and project all page has a "UTF-8" and data base also has UTF-8. but symbols look correctly in input text  ?
i tried in set content like UTF-8 and all

here is my spring controller method

//on submitting of page it is coming to here

@RequestMapping(value="/PostQueryAction",method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String question(@ModelAttribute UserQuestion  userQuestion,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,ModelMap map,@RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile file,
                HttpSession session) throws CustomException, Exception{

//here userquestion is my getters and setters

```
     HttpSession ses = httpServletRequest.getSession();
     httpServletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")
```

Comment: At this point you're better off just showing your URL and your code. There is an encoding clash somewhere, but good luck figuring out where by just discussing in abstract words.

Comment: sorry i did n't got and i given my controller also